# Where can I download a Windows 7 Ethernet Controller driver on my HP Pavilion PC500, model HP500-047c?

Tags: ethernet

Due to corporate restrictions, I had to install Windows 7 Professional on my HP Pavilion PC500 (model HP500-047c, product H5P71AA#ABA).  In the transition my Ethernet Controller and USB Controllers did not work.  I went to the HP Support site and they stated that there were no drivers.  Has somebody created drivers for this?

Comment: HP would be the only place these drivers exists.  Its very likely they do not exist for Windows 7 if you cannot find them on HP's website.  As I suspected....HP only has released Windows 8 drivers for your desktop.

Comment: Technically there is no reason [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=cp-113901-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5365462&sw_lang=) and [this](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=cp-113922-1&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&os=4132&product=5365462&sw_lang=) shouldn't work on Windows 7 due to the type of drivers they are.

Answer (score 0):

Ask HP. If they don't have one for Windows 7, then your model is not officially Windows 7 compatible, and you may be out of luck.

You're only chance: Determine which network adapter is in the machine and try getting the driver from the network adapter's manufacturer directly. Or (once you have the make/model of the adapter) try digging around on HP's site for another (older) model with that network adapter; one which provides Windows 7 drivers.

Comment: Out of some fluke or just dumb luck, the Atheros driver worked for the ethernet controller.  Now I just need to experiment with the USB 3.0 port drivers.  Thanks for your response.